# Setting up forwarding address for all users using GMail API (PHP)

Tags: php, yii, gmail-api

I'm working with the Gmail API for an internal application. ***I need to set email forwarding for both incoming and outgoing emails for all the users using the admin account.*** I'm using the Google PHP API client library in Yii.

I'm following this article. 
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Following is what I'm trying to do.

```
define('JSON_FILE', '/path/to/json/file');
$user_to_impersonate = '<My domain wide authorized admin email address>';
$scopes = [ \Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_SETTINGS_SHARING,\Google_Service_Gmail::MAIL_GOOGLE_COM];
$google_client = new \Google_Client();
$google_client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
$google_client->setScopes($scopes);
$google_client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);
$google_client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);

// setup the forwarding address
$service = new \Google_Service_Gmail($google_client);
$f = new \Google_Service_Gmail_AutoForwarding();
$f->setEnabled(TRUE);
$f->setEmailAddress('<my forwarding email address>');
$f->setDisposition("leaveInInbox");

$service->users_settings->updateAutoForwarding('me',$f)
```

I get the following error,

```
Unrecognized forwarding address
```

I know that something is not correct :). Can someone please let me know your expert response to fix this and get this working. I feel that i'm trying to set the forwarding for the email address I'm using but **not** for all the users. But I want to set the same email address for all the emails in the organisation Gmail account.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You get this error: `failedPrecondition: Unrecognized forwarding address` because you have not yet created a verified forwarding address. You need to create a forwarding address first using [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/forwardingAddresses/create) API. Then your user needs to verify that email address before you can forward any emails to it.

The problem with this approach is that you need this authorization scope `gmail.settings.sharing` in order to do it, which in turn needs Domain-wide Delegation of Authority. [See how to set it up here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation). If you do not setup this delegation you will get this error when trying to create a forwarding address: `forbidden: Access restricted to service accounts that have been delegated domain-wide authority`.

So you need to perform 2 steps:

1. Setup domain delegation of authority
2. Create a forwarding address (via API) before using it

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It may just be a formatting error, but please remove the "\" characters as it may contribute to the error you're encountering.

If you want to forward emails to and from the admin account to a list of users (all), you can use [`ForwardingAddresses`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/forwarding_settings) API for that.

Do note that messages can only be forwarded to registered and verified email addresses. This may be reason why you're getting the error. Create a forwardingAddress before you call the `updateAutoForwarding`, and hopefully it will work our right.

Happy coding!